# Restoring mongodb database

Tags: mongodb

I need help to recover data from all collections of the mongodb database. I believe the database is recoverable since i have physical backups on s3 (one .ns file and one .0 file), journal files, and the files have ~67MB of data ( not a large quantity, but very important data)

Here are steps leading to the issue I am facing (passwords masked intentionally) :

1. We have a mongodb (ver 3.0.15) database running on Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS on EC2 in localhost.
2. I created an admin user using mongo shell and the createUser command. The dots that you see below in the command are because I copied this from a Google docs document where I store my commands for easy retrieval ( hindsight is 20/20 - do not do this!).

> db.createUser({ user: "admin", pwd: "XXXXX",
> ...  roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" }, { role: "clusterAdmin", db: "admin" }, { role: "clusterMonitor", db: "admin" }, { role: "backup", db: "admin" }, { role: "readAnyDatabase", db: "admin" }, "readWriteAnyDatabase" ]
> ... })

Nevertheless, got a success message from Mongodb. So wasn't worried, yet.

```
Successfully added user: {
    "user" : "admin",
    "roles" : [
        {
            "role" : "userAdminAnyDatabase",
            "db" : "admin"
        },
        {
            "role" : "clusterAdmin",
            "db" : "admin"
        },
        {
            "role" : "clusterMonitor",
            "db" : "admin"
        },
        {
            "role" : "backup",
            "db" : "admin"
        },
        {
            "role" : "readAnyDatabase",
            "db" : "admin"
        },
        "readWriteAnyDatabase"
    ]
    }
```

3. I created a second user for a specific database. See 2 above for why you see dots below :

```
db.createUser({ user:"prod",  pwd:"YYYYYY",
... roles: [ { role: "readWrite", db: "rambabu" } ] })
Successfully added user: {
    "user" : "prod",
    "roles" : [
        {
            "role" : "readWrite",
            "db" : "rambabu"
        }
    ]
}
```

4. Then, I exited and re-entered the shell. I wanted to shutdown the mongod server and restart it in the "auth" mode. Reason I needed auth mode was to start a replicaSet so that I could initiate and complete a live migration to MongoDB Atlas of this database.

```
ubuntu@ip:~$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.15
connecting to: test
Server has startup warnings: 
2018-07-05T22:01:52.581+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2018-07-05T22:01:52.581+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled is 'always'.
2018-07-05T22:01:52.581+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2018-07-05T22:01:52.581+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2018-07-05T22:01:52.581+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag is 'always'.
2018-07-05T22:01:52.581+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2018-07-05T22:01:52.581+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
> use admin
switched to db admin
> db.shutdownServer()
2021-07-14T19:36:05.609+0000 I NETWORK  DBClientCursor::init call() failed
server should be down...
2021-07-14T19:36:05.613+0000 I NETWORK  trying reconnect to 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1) failed
2021-07-14T19:36:05.613+0000 W NETWORK  Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: errno:111 Connection refused
2021-07-14T19:36:05.613+0000 I NETWORK  reconnect 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1) failed failed couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1), connection attempt failed
> exit
bye
```

5. When I attempted to restart mongod, it gave me an error.

```
ubuntu@ip:~$ mongod --port 27017 --dbpath db --smallfiles --logpath /home/ubuntu/logs/mongodb.log 

ubuntu@ip:~/logs$ cat mongodb.log
2021-07-14T19:40:07.504+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=21385 port=27017 dbpath=db 64-bit host=ip-172-31-24-145
2021-07-14T19:40:07.504+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.0.15
2021-07-14T19:40:07.504+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: b8ff507269c382bc100fc52f75f48d54cd42ec3b
2021-07-14T19:40:07.504+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build info: Linux ip-10-71-195-23 3.13.0-24-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 10 19:11:08 UTC 2014 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
2021-07-14T19:40:07.504+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2021-07-14T19:40:07.504+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { net: { port: 27017 }, storage: { dbPath: "db", mmapv1: { smallFiles: true } }, systemLog: { destination: "file", path: "/home/ubuntu/logs/mongodb.log" } }
2021-07-14T19:40:07.526+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 98 Unable to create/open lock file: db/mongod.lock errno:13 Permission denied Is a mongod instance already running?, terminating
2021-07-14T19:40:07.526+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] dbexit:  rc: 100
```

The error message says mongod could not create/open lock file db/mongod.lock. I realized 2 things (a) I had given the incorrect --dbpath parameter, and (2) I had to delete the mongod.lock file from the correct dbpath folder

6. I deleted the mongod.lock file

```
ubuntu@ip:~/db/data$ ls -ltr
total 163852
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu       69 Aug 14  2015 storage.bson
-rw------- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 67108864 Jul  5  2018 rambabu.0
-rw------- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 16777216 Jul  5  2018 rambabu.ns
-rw------- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 16777216 Jul  5  2018 local.ns
-rw------- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 67108864 Jul  5  2018 local.0
drwxrwxr-x 2 ubuntu ubuntu     4096 Jul  5  2018 journal
-rwxrwxr-x 1 ubuntu ubuntu        0 Jul  5  2018 mongod.lock

ubuntu@ip:~/db/data$ rm mongod.lock
```

7.I restarted mongod with the following command

```
ubuntu@ip:~$ mongod --auth --port 27017 --dbpath db/data --smallfiles --logpath /home/ubuntu/logs/mongodb.log &
```

8. I opened a mongo shell and tried to authenticate into this database. And it's not letting me in. :(( I received 2 errors (a) SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL (b) Error: 18 Authentication failed. I am certain I am passing the correct values for username and password.

```
ubuntu@ip:~$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.15
connecting to: test
> use admin
switched to db admin
> use rambabu
switched to db rambabu
> db.user.count()
2021-07-14T19:44:17.135+0000 E QUERY    Error: count failed: {
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "not authorized on rambabu to execute command { count: \"user\", query: {}, fields: {} }",
    "code" : 13
}
    at Error (<anonymous>)
    at DBQuery.count (src/mongo/shell/query.js:326:11)
    at DBCollection.count (src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1046:27)
    at (shell):1:9 at src/mongo/shell/query.js:326
> db.auth(“admin”, “XXXXX”)
2021-07-14T19:46:20.902+0000 E QUERY    SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

> db.auth("admin", "XXXXX")
Error: 18 Authentication failed.
0

> exit
bye
```

9. Suspecting something got messed up/wrong, I used s3cmd to move the *.ns and *.0 files, and prealloc.* (under data/journal folder) to s3 using s3cmd.

```
ubuntu@ip:~/db/data$ ls -ltr
total 163856
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu       69 Aug 14  2015 storage.bson
-rw------- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 67108864 Jul  5  2018 rambabu.0
-rw------- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 16777216 Jul  5  2018 rambabu.ns
drwxrwxr-x 2 ubuntu ubuntu     4096 Jul 14 19:55 journal
-rw-r--r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu        6 Jul 14 19:55 mongod.lock
-rw------- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 16777216 Jul 14 19:55 local.ns
-rw------- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 67108864 Jul 14 19:55 local.0
```

10. I then created a new folder and am trying to restore my database, however all my collections are showing zero documents - except for 1 collection which is showing 2 documents from 2016.

Please advise. I can provide additional information. I need help!

Comment: In which database did you create the user?

Comment: 'admin' user created on the admin database. the 'prod' user was created on the rambabu database.

Comment: I recommend to create all users only in the 'admin' database, it is much easier to work with it.